# Undefined method confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm a Rails newbie working on my RSpec skills. I'm running into this undefined error that's leaving me scratching my head. Here it is:

```
1) Veiwing the list of movies shows the movies
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text(Movies.location)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `location' for #<Class:0x00000104bbb958>
     # ./spec/features/list_movies_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

Below is my spec file. Can you please tell me what am I overlooking here?

```rb
require "spec_helper"


feature "Veiwing the list of movies" do 
    it "shows the movies" do 

        movie1 = Movies.create(name: "The Butler", location: "New York City",
                                                        price:15.00)
        movie2 = Movies.create(name: "The Grand Master", location: "New Jersey",
                                                        price:15.00)
        movie3 = Movies.create(name: "Elysium", location: "Los Angeles", 
                                                        price:15.00 )
        movie4 = Movies.create(name:"Pacific Rim", location: "Queens NY", 
                                                        price:15.00)


        visit movies_url

        expect(page).to have_text("4 Movies")

        expect(page).to have_text(Movies.name)
        expect(page).to have_text(Movies.name)
        expect(page).to have_text(Movies.name)
        expect(page).to have_text(Movies.name)

        expect(page).to have_text(Movies.location)
        expect(page).to have_text(Movies.description)
        expect(page).to have_text("15.00")


    end

end
```

Comment: `location` is an *instance* method, not a class method; you need to reference a specific movie's location/etc.

Answer (score 2):

`Movies` is a class and thus does not have a value for `location`.  You should be checking the `location` against an instance of `Movies`: `movie1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`. For example:

```rb
expect(page).to have_text(movie1.location)
```